# how to create a dynamic dictionary with lists in it using JSON python?

Tags: python, json, list

I have dictionary formate which contain 4 lists and in the end, I want to convert it into JSON.

```
modelOutput = {
        "projectYears": 1,
        "RevSev": [
            {
                "name": "FixedSavings",
                "fixedSavingsCost": []
            }, {
                "name": "variableSavings",
                "variableSavingsCost": []
            }, {
                "name": "startUpSavings",
                "startUpSavingsCost": []
            }, {
                "name": "shutDownSavings",
                "shutDownSavingsCost": []
            },
        ],
}
```

SO if the `projectYear` value is 2 then there will be 2 dictionaries with 4 lists(Cost) with 2 random values in it in each dictionary.
expected output:

```
#if projectYear = 2
modelOutput = {
        "projectYears": 1,
        "RevSev": [
            {
                "name": "FixedSavings",
                "fixedSavingsCost": [12,22]
            }, {
                "name": "variableSavings",
                "variableSavingsCost": [11,15]
            }, {
                "name": "startUpSavings",
                "startUpSavingsCost": [32,21]
            }, {
                "name": "shutDownSavings",
                "shutDownSavingsCost": [21,33]
            },
        ],
"projectYears": 2,
        "RevSev": [
            {
                "name": "FixedSavings",
                "fixedSavingsCost": [32,23]
            }, {
                "name": "variableSavings",
                "variableSavingsCost": [23,12]
            }, {
                "name": "startUpSavings",
                "startUpSavingsCost": [14,32]
            }, {
                "name": "shutDownSavings",
                "shutDownSavingsCost": [14,13]
            },
        ],
```

Similarly, if `projectYears` is 3 then there will 3 dictionaries with 4 lists and 3 values in each of them. I was able to create the random values in the lists according to the `projectYears` but can't able to form separate dictionaries out of it.
My Approach:

```
projectLife = 3


modelOutput['RevSev'][0]['fixedSavingsCost'] = [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(projectLife)]
modelOutput['RevSev'][0]['variableSavingsCost'] = [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(projectLife)]
modelOutput['RevSev'][0]['startUpSavingsCost'] = [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(projectLife)]
modelOutput['RevSev'][0]['shutDownSavingsCost'] = [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(projectLife)]

json.dumps(modelOutput)
```

Comment: Your question does not contain a question.

Comment: What do you mean ? I just mentioned that I want dynamic dictionary. I was able to create dynamic list in it but was not able create dynamic dictionary.

Comment: The output is not a valid dict object. as it contains the same keys (RevSev, projectYears) multiple times. Are you certain that's what you're looking for?

Comment: I think you should have an array of dict in the model, rather than having dict with same key which is not valid JSON

Comment: Yes i get that its not a valid dictionary for JSON but I am new with JSON  so yeah i don't know the exact representation but can i get the expected output ? In any form, whether in dictionary or list or array.

Comment: So you're probably looking for a list of dictionaries, where each dict contains two entries: ProjectYears and RevSev. Would that make sense?

Comment: yes that would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly straightforward way of doing that, given `modelOutput` like the above as input (or even given just the number of years you'd like to have):

```
years = modelOutput["projectYears"]

randoms = lambda y: np.random.randint(10, 30, y)

res = []
for year in range(1, years+1):
    new_year = {
        "projectYears": year, 
        "RevSev": [
            {
                "name": "FixedSavings",
                "fixedSavingsCost": randoms(years)
            }, {
                "name": "variableSavings",
                "variableSavingsCost": randoms(years)
            }, {
                "name": "startUpSavings",
                "startUpSavingsCost": randoms(years)
            }, {
                "name": "shutDownSavings",
                "shutDownSavingsCost": randoms(years)
            }
        ]
    }
    res.append(new_year)
```

The result for '2' is:

```
[{'projectYears': 1,
  'RevSev': [{'name': 'FixedSavings', 'fixedSavingsCost': array([24, 22])},
   {'name': 'variableSavings', 'variableSavingsCost': array([11, 12])},
   {'name': 'startUpSavings', 'startUpSavingsCost': array([27, 22])},
   {'name': 'shutDownSavings', 'shutDownSavingsCost': array([25, 17])}]},
 {'projectYears': 2,
  'RevSev': [{'name': 'FixedSavings', 'fixedSavingsCost': array([15, 19])},
   {'name': 'variableSavings', 'variableSavingsCost': array([20, 13])},
   {'name': 'startUpSavings', 'startUpSavingsCost': array([26, 22])},
   {'name': 'shutDownSavings', 'shutDownSavingsCost': array([24, 25])}]}]
```

Comment: We can't have that in the dictionary, right? I mean instead of res(which is the dictionary).

Comment: You can, change the structure of the output. for example, have a dict in which the key is the year number. I.e {1: {RevSum: {....}}, 2: { ...